# HSQL DB SQL function calculation gives different results between HSQLDB and Oracle

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I am getting different results between HSQLDB and Oracle. Am I missing anything in the query?

```
      SELECT   (-300 / (24*60)) AS resultVal FROM DUAL;
      ---0.2083333333333333333333333333333333333333 oracle
      --0 hsqldb
```

Thanks
Jugunu

Comment: I figured a workaround...
SELECT   (-300 / (24*60.000000000000)) AS resultVal FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a property instead of using a workaround. Find out the decimal points required and set the property once with this statement.

```
set database sql avg scale 20
```

The above sets the scale at 20.